# Natural Docs comments can't have line breaks

Tags: python, comments, markdown, doc

I am using Natural Docs to generate docs from my Python codes,
my Python comments are like this:

```
Function: get_students



Parameters:
since_data: 

Returns:
res: 

{'count': 

'info': [
'mobile': '15011111111',
'nickname': 'xiaoya',
'gender': 0(unknow) or 1(male) or 2(female),
'level': 0-12,
'register_at': '2013-01-01 08:08:08',
]
}

"""
```

My config.txt is like this:

```
Language: Python

Extension: py
Shebang String: python
Line Comment: #
Block Comment: """ """
Function Prototype Ender: :
Variable Prototype Ender: =
Line Extender: /
```

and when I got the generated html, the Returns values doesn't have a line break, and I can only get a line break like this:

```
Returns:
res: 

{'count': \n

'info': [

'mobile': '15011111111',

'nickname': 'xiaoya',

'gender': 0(unknow) or 1(male) or 2(female),
'level': 0-12,
'register_at': '2013-01-01 08:08:08',
]
}
```

I have to add a blank line between each line to get a line break. What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks in the source do not translate to line breaks in the output in order to allow you writing a single paragraph of text on multiple lines; without scrolling or using the word-wrapping feature of your text editor. Web browsers render paragraphs of text in HTML in this way too.

It appears that you want a pre-formatted section in you documentation, with line-breaks as you wrote them. The lines `(start code)` and `(end)`, which I encapsulated your example in the **Returns** section with, will take care of it:

```
Returns:
res: 

(start code)
{'count': 

'info': [
'mobile': '15011111111',
'nickname': 'xiaoya',
'gender': 0(unknow) or 1(male) or 2(female),
'level': 0-12,
'register_at': '2013-01-01 08:08:08',
]
}
(end)
```

Alternatively, you could prefix every line of the example by `>` but it would be more work. Have a look at the section *Code and Text Diagrams* in the [Natural Docs comment formatting](http://naturaldocs.org/documenting/walkthrough.html#MoreFormatting) for more information.